# Set up Bar Code Scanner Database Through Parse Server: Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-platform, barcode-scanner

I have a general question.

I have built in Xcode a unique QrCode that is generated based off of a user's objectID found in Parse Server.

Ultimately, I am trying to figure out how to scan that item using a scanner such as (another iphone, other mobile scanners) and once scanned, send that objectID and other information to that same parse database.

If that is not possible, I was wondering if it would be easier to scan it directly to Microsoft Excel and then manually input that data into parse (although this could take some time).

Here is my code:

```
    import SwiftUI
    import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins
 
    let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
    let context = CIContext()
    var username = String()
    var objectId = String()

    //ViewDidLoad:

    username = "Michael"
    objectId = "Abc3432f5"
    //qrCode Formatting
    let image = generateQRCodeImage(string: objectId)
    qrCodeImage.image = image
    qrCodeImage.layer.magnificationFilter = CALayerContentsFilter(rawValue: kCISamplerFilterNearest)

   //Functions
   func generateQRCodeImage (string: String) -> UIImage {
    
    let data = Data(string.utf8)
    filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
    
    if let qrCodeImage = filter.outputImage {
        if let qrCodeCGImage = context.createCGImage(qrCodeImage, from: qrCodeImage.extent) {
            
            return UIImage(cgImage: qrCodeCGImage)
            }
         }
            return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
```

And if so, is there a way to check if the data has already been uploaded to the excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Question is unclear: you generated the QR Code. then you expect another phone to scan it from the first phone? or do you send it somewhere? and what is "parse database"?

Comment: 1) Yes, either a phone or one of the standard scanners that you see at generally restaurants like Chipotle or Starbucks that track their rewards program.
2) I am trying to send it to the same database that holds user information
3) The server is Bitnami EC2 instance run thru AWS

Comment: Still not sure what is your difficulty: the other device scans qr, parses it, and sends parsed data to server (this is all pretty standard stuff).

Comment: yeah figured i would create a scanner app, parse the scanned qr, and then push it to the same parse server. This makes more sense.